# Solving the trigonometric equation $\sqrt{2}\sin(⁡2x)=-\sqrt{3\sin(⁡x) + 3\cos(⁡x) + 8\cos^4⁡(x-\pi/4)}$

Tags: trigonometry

My problem is to solve the following equation:

$$\sqrt{2}\sin(⁡2x)=-\sqrt{3\sin(⁡x) + 3\cos(⁡x) + 8\cos^4⁡(x-\pi/4)}$$

I've narrowed it down to

$$3\sin(⁡x) + 3\cos(⁡x) + 2 + 8\sin(⁡x)\cos(⁡x) = 0.$$

That's as far as I can get. It seems so simple, but I just can't find the next step(s).

Comment: How about using $(2\sin x + 2\cos x)^2 = 4 + 8\sin x \cos x$

Comment: If $\sin x+\cos x=t,t^2=?$

Comment: @Snaw I've tried this, but I still don't get any further from it.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @SamMylle By $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ you get $(2\sin x + 2\cos x)^2 = 4 + 8\sin x \cos x$. Substitute this into your second equation and you get $3\sin x + 3\cos x + 2 + (2\sin x + 2\cos x)^2 - 4 = 0$ which is the same thing as $3\sin x + 3\cos x -2 + 4(\sin x + \cos x)^2 = 0$. If you now denote $t=\sin x + \cos x$ you get a quadratic equation in $t$.

Comment: @Snaw I love you, thx

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Using auxiliary angle gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{2} \sin (2 x) &=-\sqrt{3 \sin x+3 \cos x+8 \cos ^{4}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \\
&=-\sqrt{3 \sqrt{2} \cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+8 \cos ^{4}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $ y=x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, then
$$\sqrt{2} \cos \left(2 y\right)=-\sqrt{3 \sqrt{2} \cos y+8 \cos ^{4} y}$$

Squaring both sides yields $$
2 \cos ^{2}(2 y)=3 \sqrt{2} \cos y+8 \cos ^{4} y
$$
Using double-angle formula gives

$$
\begin{array}{l}
2\left(2 \cos ^{2} y-1\right)^{2}=3 \sqrt{2} \cos y+8 \cos ^{4} y \\
8 \cos ^{4} y-8 \cos ^{2} y+2=3 \sqrt{2} \cos y+8 \cos ^{4} y \\
8 \cos ^{2} y+3 \sqrt{2} \cos y-2=0  \\
\displaystyle \cos y=\frac{-3 \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{82}}{16}
\end{array}
$$
After checking for $\sin(2x)<0$, we can conclude that the solutions are$$
\begin{array}{l} \\ \displaystyle x=\frac{(8 n+1) \pi}{4} \pm \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{82}-3 \sqrt{2}}{16}\right),
\end{array}
$$
where $ n\in Z$.